# Redirect to new url while saving the url structure and query parameters in php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, redirect

I have a WordPress site that is getting traffic from a specific location,
The URL comes with many query parameters that I want to keep, what I want to do is

1. If we are on mobile redirect to different URL but keep all the query parameters as is (REQUEST_URI)
2. If we are on desktop take the query parameters and include them in a hidden field on the page.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure its the right way to go

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ak_redirect_to_url' );
function ak_redirect_to_url() {

    // Only do redirect if custom field is true
    $do_referral = get_field('do_referral') ? true : false;
    // Get the URL
    $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    // Site HTTP_HOST
    $referral = 'original.com';
    // New HTTP_HOST to change
    $new_url = 'something.com';

    $new_with_query = str_replace($referral, $new_url ,$url );

    if ( !wp_is_mobile() && !empty($new_with_query) && $do_referral === true ) {

        // Code here to put query parameters in a hidden field in a form
        //exit;

    } elseif ( wp_is_mobile() && !empty($new_with_query) && $do_referral === true ) {
        wp_redirect( $new_with_query, 307 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

This is my ajax to retrieve the query parameters and append them in the html on the page.

```
function ak_ajax_hidden_input() {

    $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $response = array(
        'url' => $url
    );

    wp_send_json_success( $response );
    wp_die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ak_ajax_hidden_input', 'ak_ajax_hidden_input' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ak_ajax_hidden_input', 
    'ak_ajax_hidden_input' );
```

My problem is that by the time the AJAX is checking the page URL its returning the AJAX url - /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and this is not what I need.

Comment: So what is the real issue you are facing now?

Comment: @Chiel thanks for the feedback, the question was not clear, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: So basically (correct me if i’m wrong) you want to, if mobile, redirect “example.com/path/to/folder/?foo=bar&var=x” to “example.com/mobile/path/to/folder/?foo=bar&var=x”?